# Change urls' scheme from http to https in DRF api-root

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created an API, deployed it on the server on 8443 port and setup cloudflare's SSL certificates.

Everything works perfectly, but I got a problem that urls in api-root still have **http** scheme. Also I set `X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme header in nginx.conf`. What could be the problem?

Comment: you should consider redirecting from http to https from nginx conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. I had to add `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')` to my `settings.py`